# Ratio of sums of $\infty$-norms of vectors

Tags: norms

For any vector $w\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ let $\|w\|:=\|w\|_\infty = \max_i |w_i|.$ Let $w\geq 0$ mean that $w$ is non-negative in each co-ordinate.

For $0<\alpha<\frac 14,$ I am interested in the quantity

$$f(\alpha):=\sup_{u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n, u,v\geq 0, n\geq 1} \frac{\|(1-\alpha)u-\alpha v\|+\|(1-\alpha)v-\alpha u\|+2\alpha \|u+v\|}{\|u\|+\|v\|}~.$$

By the triangle inequality, we get $f(\alpha)\leq 1+2\alpha.$

Or in other words, for $\alpha = p(1-p)$ with $0<p<\frac 12,$ this means $$f(p(1-p)) \leq 1+2p-2p^2.$$

By choosing $n=2$ and $u = \begin{bmatrix} p(1-p) \\ p(1-p) \end{bmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{bmatrix} p^2 \\ (1-p)^2 \end{bmatrix},$ we get

$$f(p(1-p))\geq 1+p-2p^2.$$

I conjecture that $f(p(1-p)) \leq 1+p-2p^2.$

Any proof or counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do no better than $1+\alpha$.

Lower bound: Take $u=(1,0,1)$ and $v=(0,1,1)$.

Upper bound, the nominator is bounded by $(1-\alpha)\|u\|+(1-\alpha)\|v\|+2\alpha(\|u\|+\|v\|)$.